# Refreshing a wpf databinding after object has been updated

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have a object in a presenter connected to a view. Inside my XAMTL I have the following:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=PSV, Path=Presenter.Portfolio.Name}"/>
```

Now when the control is created, Portfolio is null, then i run another method which sets Portfolio. I've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged but so far, I've not been able to trigger to hookup to the binding.

Can someone give me tips? Can I bind to a property of a property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding always works with the DataContext you would need to set your Presenter into the local DataContext.  For example you could do this in the constructor of your Window or UserControl:

```
this.DataContext = new Presenter();
```

Your binding would then change to:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=PSV, Path=Portfolio.Name}"/>
```

The Presenter part of your former path is implicit in the DataContext.

This way the DataContext is watching for the NotifyChanged events and will update the view properly when Portfolio changes from null to having a value.

In answer to the final part of your question, binding to a property of a property does work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression.aspx
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatetarget.aspx
help

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly, this will work just fine. Some things to try:

1. Try setting a dummy portfolio with a dummy name in your presenter's constructor so you can make sure the binding is actually correct.
2. If it still doesn't work after #1, look in your output window for any binding errors.
3. If it did work after #1, make sure the portfolio you are setting has a name at the time it was constructed. If not, your portfolio class will also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the event when the `Name` is set.

Failing all that, please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented, are you making sure to fire the PropertyChanged event in your Portfolio.Name setter?

```
string _name;
public string Name
{
get 
{
   return _name;
}
set
{
   _name = value;
   // Alert the databinding engine about changes to the source value
   OnPropertyChanged("Name");
}

void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(propertyName);
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion
```